# Loop in a node chain

Tags: c#

Suppose I have 100 nodes:

```
        Node<double> n1 = new Node<double>(1);
        Node<double> n2 = new Node<double>(2);
        Node<double> n3 = new Node<double>(3);
        Node<double> n4 = new Node<double>(4);
        Node<double> n5 = new Node<double>(5);
        Node<double> n6 = new Node<double>(6);
                       .
                       .
                       .
        Node<double> n100 = new Node<double>(100);
```

And I want to connect them, then I can write:

```
        n1.SetNext(n2);
        n2.SetNext(n3);
        n3.SetNext(n4);
        n4.SetNext(n5);
        n5.SetNext(n6);
             .
             .
             .
        n99.SetNext(n100);
```

but, how can I do this an one loop? I tried something like:

```
            Node<double> pos = n1;
            int i = 1;
            while (pos != null)
            {
                pos.SetValue(i);
                pos.SetNext(new Node<double>(0));
                pos = pos.GetNext();
                i++;
            }
```

Comment: Do you really have 100 nodes declared like that? If so, why? It would be much easier to just create the nodes and link them in a loop. Better yet, you could probably use a build in class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Also, adding to what @EvanTrimboli said, why are the nodes individually declared instead of being part of a collection? If you had a collection you can loop back around by using the modulus operator.

Comment: Also, please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Node<double>> nodes = new List<Node<double>>(100);

for (Int32 i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
    nodes.Add(new Node<double>(i));

for (Int32 i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    nodes[i].SetNext(nodes[i + 1]);
```

Using your approach, I would go for:

```
Node<double> n = new Node<double>(0);
Int32 i = 1;

while (i <= 100)
{
    n.SetValue(i);
    n.SetNext(new Node<double>(0));
    n = n.GetNext();

    ++i;
}
```

Comment: If I print `Console.WriteLine(n.GetValue());` outside the loop the output is zero, and this `Console.WriteLine(n.GetNext().GetValue());` outside the loop gives exception: `System.NullReferenceException`